# What was the epic poem referenced in An Artificial Night by Seanan McGuire?

Tags: story-identification, books, mythology, poetry

Near the end of *An Artificial Night*, book three in the October Daye series starring October "Toby" Daye, towards the end of the book, she is a prisoner of Blind Michael and the Wild Hunt.

The way she escapes is directly related to events in an epic poem I think was Irish, involving horses, the Wild Hunt, a Lady or maybe a Queen, and many people coming to rescue her all at once, declaring they intend to do so.

What is this literary/mythological/poetic reference? I think it is named specifically in the book, and there are excerpts of the text in that section of the story.

Comment: Thanks for the edit to fix the author's name, ten thousand curses upon autocorrect!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [The Ballad of Tam Lin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tam_Lin)

The Ballad is the story of a young woman named Janet, who meets and "gets to know" (wink wink, nudge nudge) Tam Lin, a knight in not-entirely-willing service to the fairy queen.

Janet interrupts the queen's Halloween Ride and pulls Tam Lin from his horse. After enduring several trials where Tam Lin is transformed into beasts and dangerous objects,she successfully claims him for herself.

There isn't one single official version of the ballad, but you can find versions with the quotes that McGuire used.

And of course McGuire adds her own twists to the ballad. This is not the last time the story will be relevant to Toby's tale.  (And that's all I'm going to say about that. Have fun reading! )

Comment: Thank you so much!